# How to properly parse a tcp packet in java?

Tags: java, tcp, binary, packet

I currently have a simple TCP server, which calls a function and passes it the binary TCP payload in the form of a byte array on every new incoming packet, what is the proper way to parse it?

I tried doing it by just slicing it into different byte arrays and processing them separately, but my packets include a variable-length datatype, which I am unable to split from the other data. It really seems like it's not what I should do and I think there is a better way to do it

readVarInt() is a function that parses the variable-length datatype and returns the result and the length of the unparsed datatype in an int[] array
PacketHeader is a class that that has size, id and body fields, id and size are already parsed and the body field contains everything else after the size and id bytes

```java
int[] parsedProtocolVersion = Main.readVarInt(packetHeader.body);
System.out.println(parsedProtocolVersion[0] + ' ' + parsedProtocolVersion[1]);
int[] parsedServerAddressSize = Main.readVarInt( packetHeader.body.subList(parsedProtocolVersion[1], packetHeader.body.size()));
System.out.println("parsed 1 " + parsedServerAddressSize[1] + " " + parsedServerAddressSize[0]);
String parsedServerAddress = String.valueOf(packetHeader.body.subList(parsedServerAddressSize[1], parsedServerAddressSize[0]));
System.out.println("parsed 2");
int parsedServerPort = Integer.parseUnsignedInt((packetHeader.body.subList(parsedServerAddressSize[1]+parsedProtocolVersion[1], parsedServerAddressSize[1]+parsedProtocolVersion[1]+2).toString()));
System.out.println("parsed 3");
int[] parsedNextState = Main.readVarInt(packetHeader.body.subList(parsedServerAddressSize[1]+parsedProtocolVersion[1]+2, packetHeader.body.size()));
System.out.println("parsed 4");
return String.format("%d %s %d %d",parsedProtocolVersion[0], parsedServerAddress, parsedServerPort, parsedNextState[0]);
```

Comment: Because you're working with the Minecraft server protocol, variable-length integers are read byte-by-byte. I recommend using the method found at: https://wiki.vg/Data_types#VarInt_and_VarLong

Comment: I already use these methods, I'm talking about parsing the packet as a whole

Comment: You wouldn't parse the packet as a whole; you'd wrap it in something, such as a `ByteBuffer`, and read each field separately. You can do this because the packet gives you its length (including the length of its opcode).

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need, now I am able to parse packets properly.

Comment: There is no such thing as a TCP packet. There are IP packets and TCP segments, but your application doesn't receive either of them. What you receive is a byte stream.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying, I'm still learning about all the networking stuff and probably don't know a lot of things